# How do I name a file by a variable name in Python?

Tags: python, variables, io

I want to take as input the name of a network, and then I want a file to be saved using the same name as the variable. Is there a way to take a variable and then name a file the variable name?

For instance, say I have the network called facebook saved as a dictionary. Can I somehow take that variable name and use it as a filename?

This is all in Python.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have a variable whose name you don't know when you're writing the code, and how do you want to access it in the open call?

Comment: In Python, variables are not boxes. They are simply names. If you don't know the name of the variable, you won't be able to access it...

Comment: Do you want to write the actual variable name to a file? or the variable content?

Answer (score 9):

You can declare a value like the following:

```
# Let's create a file and write it to disk.
filename = "facebook.txt"

# Create a file object:
# in "write" mode
FILE = open(filename,"w")

# Write all the lines at once:
FILE.writelines("Some content goes here")

# Close
FILE.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

if you have

```
data=['abc','bcd']
```

you can do

```
file = open('{0}.txt'.format(data[0]),"w")
```

which will create file as
    abc.txt

Write some text to a file

```
file.writelines('xyz')

file.close()
```

Comment: You override built-in class `file` in such way. You should rather avoid this and name it `file_`. Maybe I just nitpick, but remember that it's also read by people that aren't aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

i don't understand you , cause your question not very clear ,, anyway i'll post two solution

in case you want the file name to named as the name of variable

i'd suggest using this code

```
for i in locals():
  if 'variable name' is i:IObject = open(i+".txt",'w')#i've added .txt extension in case you want it text file 
IObject.write("Hello i'm file name.named with the same name of variable")
```

or otherwise

```
name_of_file = raw_input("Enter the name")
IOjbect = open(name_of_file+".txt","w")
IObject.write("Hey There")
```

Answer (score 0):

Would that do it?

```
n_facebook = {'christian': [22, 34]}
n_myspace = {'christian': [22, 34, 33]}

for network in globals():
    if network.startswith('n_'):
        # here we got a network
        # we save it in a file ending with _network.txt without n_ in beginning
        file(network[2:] + '_network.txt', 'w').write(str(globals()[network]))
```

this file saves n_facebook to facebook_network.txt. myspace also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying this approach and I'm getting a very odd issue, my items are being saved to the file a program run behind. So if I run the file once, nothing will happen. A second time, the information from the run will be saved.

```
f = open("results_{0}.txt".format(counter), 'w')
f.write("Agent A vs. Champion\n"
      + "Champion wins = "
      + str(winsA1)
      + " Agent A wins = "
      + str(winsB1))
f.write("\n\nAgent B vs. Champion\n"
      + "Champion wins = "
      + str(winsA2)
      + " Agent B wins = "
      + str(winsB2))
f.write("\n\nRandom vs. Champion\n"
      + "Champion wins = "
      + str(winsA3)
      + " Random wins = "
      + str(winsB3))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to have the file name be something that the user inputs:

```
#Here the user inputs what the file name will be.
name_of_file = input("Enter what you want the name of the file to be.")

#Then the file is created using the user input.
newfile = open(name_of_file + ".txt","w")

#Then information is written to the file.
newfile.write("It worked!")

#Then the file is closed.
newfile.close()
```